# Copy and insert row (with a minor change) in dataframe ABOVE a variable

Tags: r

I'm really new to R, and struggling with the following.  If anyone could suggest where I look for a solution or point me in the right direction, I'd be forever grateful.

I have a dataset where I'd like to copy a row and insert that copy with an amendment (in this case appending ", USA) into the same dataframe when it find a value in the second column (a before and after dput are below).

I can find examples of duplicating row based on a regular pattern (ie.  copy and insert every fourth row), but I'm not sure how I'd do that if the pattern isn't regular.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
before = structure(list(Teams = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Blue", "Green", 
"Red", "Yellow"), class = "factor"), City = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"California", "Chicago", "New York ", "Ohio"), class = "factor"), 
    Jan = c(NA, NA, 156.156, NA, NA, 818.87, 1586.4, NA, NA, 
    87.1, NA, NA, 873.4, 41.1, 1886.5), Feb = c(NA, NA, 1856, 
    NA, NA, 17.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.8, NA, 187)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

after = structure(list(Teams = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow"), class = "factor"), City = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "California", "California, USA", "Chicago", 
"Chicago, USA", "New York", "New York, USA", "Ohio", "Ohio, USA"
), class = "factor"), Jan = c(NA, NA, NA, 156.156, NA, NA, NA, 
818.87, 1586.4, NA, NA, NA, 87.1, NA, NA, NA, 873.4, 41.1, 1886.5
), Feb = c(NA, NA, NA, 1856, NA, NA, NA, 17.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.8, NA, 187)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: I'd suggest thinking about the structure of your data frame. Is there some reason that it needs to be structured in this way? To me, it makes more sense to add a new column named `Country`.

Comment: I could add the additional column named country, but I'm still not sure how that would help be add an additional row above (City != "")?

Comment: I guess I'm missing something pretty simple, I'm sorry if my question is too obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
before %>% mutate(City = ifelse(City != "", paste0(City, ", USA"), ""))
```

Basically, you consider working around columns.

You can also use base R, which is more cumbersome. You need to convert your `City` to character first.

```
before$City = as.character(before$City)
before[before[, 2] != "", 2] = paste0(before[before[, 2] != "", 2], ",USA")
```

**Edits:**

I don't have an elegant way. This is an ugly for loop solution.

```
before$City = as.character(before$City)
df=NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(before)){
  df=rbind(df,before[i,])
  if(before[i,2]!=""){
    before[i,2]=paste0(before[i,2], ",USA")
    df=rbind(df,before[i,])
  }
}
df
```

Comment: Thanks - I need to keep the original line as well, so I'm wondering if there is a way to duplicate the row above row where (City != "")?

Comment: In that case, its a general loop problem. Please see the edits.